# Prevent CommonJS module imported into ES module from executing code

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, commonjs

I am attempting to import a CommonJS module (KeyboardJS) into some tests I have written in an ES module.

Here is my test code to give you an idea:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
import assert from 'assert'
import keyboardjs from 'keyboardjs' // <-- this line throws an error

// create mocked window object
const window = new JSDOM().window
const document = window.document

// pass this to keyboardjs?
keyboardjs.watch(document)
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Cannot find window functions addEventListener or attachEvent.
    at Keyboard.watch (./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:614:19)
    at Keyboard.setContext (./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:587:14)
    at new Keyboard (./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:439:12)
    at ./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:1076:18
    at ./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:2:83
    at Object.<anonymous> (./node_modules/keyboardjs/dist/keyboard.js:5:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async formattedImport (./node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (./node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (./node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:88:20)
    at async singleRun (./node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (./node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
```

It appears that `keyboardjs` is attempting to access the `window` object *while it is loaded*, which of course can't work since I am loading it in some test code.

Is there some special way to import it without triggering this behavior?

Comment: But why it can't find the `window.addEventListener()` function? Is `window` undefined?

Comment: Yes, this code is running as part of a unit test, so `window` is undefined.

Comment: Then why not mock the module? I think this now integration test rather than unit test!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated KeyboardJS so it doesn't throw like this on initialization, which means your code should work now.

That said I would recommend checking out my new library called [Keystrokes](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes). It's the successor to KeyboardJS and comes with easier to use and more modern interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#examples).

You can use an `import` function, which returns a Promise for when the module is imported.

`JSDOM` can be imported first, and then used to create an embedded window object which we then add to the global scope.

Then, we can import `keyboardjs` using the same mechanism.

Here is  roughly the code I ended up with:

```
// import JSDOM first
import('jsdom').then(async module => {
  const window = new module.JSDOM().window

  // now set the global window object to the JSDOM window
  globalThis.window = window

  // _now_ import keyboardjs
  const keyboardjs = await import('keyboardjs')
  const document = window.document
  return { keyboardjs, document }
}).then(({ keyboardjs, document }) => {
  // test code goes here, and can use keyboardjs and document
})
```